# Length $3$ strings is $A^*$ for $A=\{0,1\}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A=\{0, 1\}$. How many strings of length $3$ are there in $A^{*}$?

Comment: $|A|^3$ ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^*$ contains precisely all finite binary strings. Therefore, there will be precisely one length $3$ element for every one of the $\boxed{8}$ binary numbers from $000$ to $111$.